# How to make link clickable or unclickable base on text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing website which allow user to insert text automatically to textarea when they click on link "Thank you" and "Good luck". After they click on which link, that link will be hide. Now, i can insert text to textarea when they click on that link. What i want now if user does not click on that both link, the Tweet link below textarea will unclickable and after user click that both links, the Tweet link will be clickable.

**Here is my current code**

**HTML**

```
<a class="click" href="">Thank you</a><span style="display: none;">Thank you</span>&nbsp;
<a class="click" href="">Good luck</a><span style="display: none;">Good luck</span><br/>
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="replycontent" id="replycontent"></textarea><br/>
<a id="tweet" href="#">Tweet</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".click").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#replycontent").append($(this).next('span').text() );
    $(this).hide();
})
```

Can anyone help me with the above requirement?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$('#tweet').click(function (e) {
    if ($('.click:visible').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        alert('Need to click more');
    }
});
```

If the number of visible `.click` items is greater than zero, do nothing.
When it hits zero show a message.

Answer (score 1):

To remove href for anchor tag,

> $('#tweet').removeAttr('href');

To add href for anchor tag,

> $("#tweet").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")

Remove href tag when the page loads, add href when user clicks the first link.  If you want both *".click"* links to be clicked you can add counter variable inside the function to track the clicks.